# Why does this (.replace) work on chrome and not on safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, safari

I need to get rid of the comma from an input text and it works fine on chrome but not on safari. Why?

`console.log($('#m_currency').val().replace(/,/g, ""));`

`console.log($('#m_currency').val().replace(/,/g, ""));`
`console.log($('#m_currency').val().replace(",", ""));`

Comment: Does Safari maybe use a different character for the comma? Can you take the actual value you get and supply that?

Comment: I use it for an input type text and for instance if I digit "9,000" the console log gives me back "9000" on chrome but nothing on safari

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. On both Safari and Chrome for me (on my Mac, US Keyboard), the comma is removed in all 3 versions of your code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.